# Specific distibution recommendation

Tags: software-rec, distribution-choice

I want to ask the distro cosmopolitans of you for a distibution recommendation for my special needs.

I'm coming from arch linux, which is really fine I like to be virtually on upstream software and I like not to be forced to format my system every half year. Super choice, but I am not satisfied with package releases (e.g. recently broke VMplayer since a kernel compiled with gcc from testing was released). However I am searching a distribution which is almost as bleeding edge like arch and where I am free to choose non-free packages, unlike fedora, which was a strong favorite. It should be a rolling release, easy to use (no gentoo) and capable of serving the daily "productive" needs.

Is there such a distro at all?

Comment: Stack Exchange is really not the place for opinion polls.

Comment: I did not ask for an opinion, The answer is want really offers not much room for an opinion, if there is one at all.

Answer (score 1):

Manuel, you have incompatible requirements. You want bleeding edge and production. IMHO you do not need super duper fresh packages, but stable packages. You can take a look on CentOS or Oracle Linux. Both of them offer quite contemporary packages plus rock solid reliability